# What is the difference between findRooms and findRoomLists API in microsoft graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have gone through https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_findroomlists and https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_findrooms docs provided by microsoft azure for findRooms and findRoomLists APIs but not able to get what is exact difference between two.
Can someone explain me exact difference between these two APIs.

For me these are same.

Thanks
Ajay Tiwari

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation link you posted:

> Get the room lists defined in a tenant.
>
> Tenants can organize meeting rooms into room lists. Each meeting room and room list is represented by an emailAddress instance. You can get all the room lists in the tenant, get all the rooms in the tenant, or get all the rooms in a specific room list.

As stated above, tenants can organize rooms into groups called room lists. An example of room lists would be: a room list for a conference rooms in a building.

More literature to read if needed:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633471(v=exchg.141).aspx